# Is there a Java lib that can evaluate SQL style date functions from a String?

Tags: java, sql, parsing, sql-date-functions

I'm looking for a way to read a date command from a text file and evaluate it.

As an example consider this MySQL command: `DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`
Something similar to that will be in the text file.

The closer I can get to an SQL syntax, the better.

Are there any Java libs that can evaluate text SQL date and time commands?

The best idea I've come up with so far is to make the commands some SQL implementation, pull the command out of the text file and run it against a DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/): run your commands against this DB. It is fully functional pure java database.